# How to use sortUsingFunction (or sortUsingSelector) to sort NSMutableArray of objects containing arrays

Tags: iphone, ios, sorting, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I have an `NSMutableArray` of model objects. Each model object contains an `NSArray` of `NSNumbers`. I want to sort the model objects based on the lowest `NSNumber` value from their respective number arrays.

What's the best way to implement this using `sortUsingFunction` (or `sortUsingSelector`)? I'm still supporting `iOS 3.2` so I can't use blocks.

Currently, I'm tagging each model object with the lowest `NSNumber` value, and then using an `NSSortDescriptor` on the tag key... but I'm sure there's a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the cleanest or most efficient way to do it, but you can write a method for your model class `- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(MyModel *)otherModel`, which you would:

1. Sort the `NSArray` of `NSNumbers` for both the `self` and `otherModel` objects using `sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)`
2. Get the `NSNumber` object at index 0 for both of the two sorted arrays you created in step 1 (which will be the lowest value in each array)
3. Return the result of `[lowestSelfNumber compare:lowestOtherNumber]`

Then you can sort the mutable array with `sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)`

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution more than my tagging method.